# Access a list within a dropdown in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Im trying to access a list within a dropdown in Javascript. So I have an object called `System` (which is the object stored in the dropdown) and this has a List of `Collections`. I am new to Javascript and not sure what the correct syntax should be to access the list.

So this is the form that contains the dropdown:

```
<form:form id="systemForm" method="post" action="/application/SystemSave" commandName="systemForm">
    <form:select path="uSelectedSystemId" id="uSystemId">
        <c:forEach var="system" items="${systemsList}">
            <form:option value="${system.id}" label="${system.name}" />
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select> 
</form:form>
```

and this is the setup of the `System` object (from Java):

```
public class System {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Collection> collections;
}
```

and this is the setup of the `SystemForm` used to store the values:

```
public class SystemForm {
private String fUpdateSystemName;
private String uSelectedSystemId;
    private List<Collection> uCollections;
}
```

I guess I need some sort of hidden field within the loop that stores the values but im not sure of the correct syntax. I could just rehit the database and get all `Collections` based on the `systemID` but I dont think this is the correct way of doing things seeing as the information should already be available.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The output would depend on what you want to do with `system.collections` next. Do you want to display them in another dropdown? Or just as a list/plain text? Or not display them at all and use them in an internal JavaScript object?

Comment: Nope, I don't want to display the collections, only to use it to repopulate the original object so it can be saved by Hibernate. I think it may be a better idea to use the ID of the System to get the System object from the database which will already have the Collections populated and then update the values for anything that has been modified and send back to the database to save. That way Hibernate wont start moaning as I was going to in effect create a fake object by manually setting its ID.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <form:form id="systemForm" method="post" action="/application/SystemSave" commandName="systemForm">
   <select  id="uSystemId">
        <c:forEach var="system" items="${systemsList}">
            <option value="${system.id}" label="${system.name}" />
        </c:forEach>
    </select> 
</form:form>
```

i dont know exactly this will meet your requirement or not.

Comment: So I just remove the path? How do I access it from the `SystemForm`?

Comment: That is what I use the access the selected values from the controller (Java side) - I have put an example of the setup in the question.